# Get-ChildItem is using current Dir instead of Dir specified in variable

Tags: powershell, directory

**Ouline -**

I have 300,000+ folders containing subfolders and files.

I am trying to flatten each directory so that subfolders are removed and all files are brought to their respective parent directory.

Unfortunately, the Get-ChildItem cmdlet runs in the location of the .ps1 file and not those specified in the .txt file.

I have been trying to troubleshoot this for hours, any help would be greatly apprecieated.

**Process -**

First, I run a .ps1 file that retrieves the parent folder locations from a text file and calls a custom module:

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\Users\ccugnet\Desktop\test.txt") | ForEach-Object {
    Import-Module MyFunctions
    fcopy -SourceDir $line -DestinationDir $line
    Remove-Module MyFunctions
}
```

Second, the custom module moves the child items to the parent folder, appending an incrementing digit to the end of the file name for duplicate files:

```
function fcopy ($SourceDir,$DestinationDir)
{
    Get-ChildItem $SourceDir -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false } | ForEach-Object {
        $SourceFile = $_.FullName
        $DestinationFile = $DestinationDir + $_
        if (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
            $i = 0
            while (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
                $i += 1
                $DestinationFile = $DestinationDir + $_.basename + $i + $_.extension
            }
        } else {
            Move-Item -Path $SourceFile -Destination $DestinationFile -Verbose -Force -WhatIf
        }
        Move-Item -Path $SourceFile -Destination $DestinationFile -Verbose -Force -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Text file contents:

```
"C:\Users\ccugnet\Desktop\Dir_Flatten\Fox, Hound & Hunter"
"C:\Users\ccugnet\Desktop\Dir_Flatten\Cat, Hat"
"C:\Users\ccugnet\Desktop\Dir_Flatten\Alice"
"C:\Users\ccugnet\Desktop\Dir_Flatten\Beetle | Juice"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $line is empty

```
PS P:\> [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\Users\ccugnet\Desktop\test.txt") | ForEach-Object {
    $line
}
```

Try $_

```
PS P:\> [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\Users\ccugnet\Desktop\test.txt") | ForEach-Object {
    $_
}
"C:\Users\ccugnet\Desktop\Dir_Flatten\Fox, Hound & Hunter"
"C:\Users\ccugnet\Desktop\Dir_Flatten\Cat, Hat"
"C:\Users\ccugnet\Desktop\Dir_Flatten\Alice"
"C:\Users\ccugnet\Desktop\Dir_Flatten\Beetle | Juice"
```

Comment: Thanks Sayan, you were correct that the $line variable was empty - I included `$line = $_` and removed the quotation marks from the text file. The script then started working as expected. I could not add the file paths to the .ps1 files as it needs to run on 300,000+ folders. I'm worried that would cause issues with loading.